# Empty state in component ( react redux )

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Have problem with `state` in my component. 
I'm trying to get status from my reducer but `state` is empty just getting `undefined`

**Here is my `actionCreator`**

```
export function checkLogin() {
return function(dispatch){
    return sessionApi.authCheck().then(response => {
        dispatch(authSuccess(true)); 
    }).catch(error => {
        throw(error)
    })
 }
}
```

**My reducer**

```
export const authStatus = (state = {}, action) => {
switch(action.type){
    case AUTH_FALSE:
            return{
                status: action.status
            }
    case AUTH_TRUE:
            return {
                ...state,
                status: action.status
            };
    default:
        return state;
  }
};
```

And here is my component where i'm trying to get state

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
 return {
 status: state.status
  }
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch:any) => {
  const changeLanguage = (lang:string) => dispatch(setLocale(lang));
  const checkAuth = () => dispatch(checkLogin());
  return { changeLanguage, checkAuth }
};

@connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)
```

I need to get `status` from the state

**Component**

```
import * as React from "react";
import  Navigation  from './components/navigation';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { setLocale } from 'react-redux-i18n';
import cookie from 'react-cookie';
import {checkLogin} from "./redux/actions/sessionActions";

class App extends React.Component<any, any> {
  constructor(props:any) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      path: this.props.location.pathname
    };
  }
  componentDidMount(){
    this.props.checkAuth();
    this.props.changeLanguage(cookie.load('lang'));
  }
  componentWillUpdate(){
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Navigation path={this.state.path} />
          {this.props.children}
      </div>
    )
  }

}
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    status: state.status
  }
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch:any) => {
  const changeLanguage = (lang:string) => dispatch(setLocale(lang));
  const checkAuth = () => dispatch(checkLogin());
  return { changeLanguage, checkAuth }
};

@connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)
export class Myapp
extends App {}
```

Comment: once you pass the state to the component props with `mapStateToProps`, it should be accessible through the props of the component. Are you trying to access `this.props.status` ? You should show the full component so people can understand your problem.

Comment: yeah 
i'm trying to get data from `this.props.status` and getting `undefined` 
I have no idea why it going like this

Comment: there could be a number of reasons, it is hard to tell ? have you included your reducer inside the `combineReducers` function ? Are you matching any of the cases in your reducer ?

Comment: Also you forgot ```...state,``` in case AUTH_FALSE. that could be the reason

Comment: i'm not passing that case AUTH_FALSE 
I have to get it work with second case 
and ofcourse i included it 
I appreciate your help!

Comment: and yes in my action i'm matching this 
when i just put `console.log` in that case AUTH_TRUE 

It works but return - don't

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135521/discussion-between---and-kevin-amiranoff).

Comment: Try to get it with `componentWillReceiveProps(next) { next.state }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot access props that are asynchronous inside of the `constructor`. As the `constructor` will be executed only once, when you instantiate your component. When you instantiate your component your asynchronous call has not responded yet, therefore `this.props.status` is undefined.

You could use `componentWillReceiveProps` from React lifecycle methods for example:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
  console.log(nextProps.status);
}
```

This method will be executed everytime a prop connected, or passed, to the component will change.
You could also use `this.props.status` inside of the `render` as this one is also executed everytime a prop changed.

For a better understanding of react lifecycle you could have the look at the different methods available, here : https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html